# Unrelated CSS IDs Affecting Each Other

Tags: html, css

I'm currently redesigning a website of mine to have two columns. The left column is a sidebar with some links and text and the right column is the body (not `<body>`) of the page. The problem I'm having is that the CSS rules of two completely separate elements on the page are affecting both elements.

Since that probably doesn't make sense, here's my code:

**CSS**

```
#left h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6 {
    padding: 10px;
    color: black;
}
#right h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6 {
    padding: 0px 10px;
}
```

**HTML**

```
<div id="left">
    <?php include('sidebar.php'); ?>
</div>

<div id="right">
    <h2>Blah blah blah welcome</h2>
    <p>Yadda yadda yadda.</p>

    <div class="sep"></div>

    <h2>Etc etc</h2>
    <p>The end.</p>
</div>
```

What I'm trying to do is remove the top and bottom padding on the `#right` headers, but for some reason, whatever I do, the CSS ids are affecting each other. Not only can I see it physically, when I inspect the code in Google Chrome, both elements have the rules for both `#left` and `#right` attributed to them. Essentially, the `#right` headers still have the top and bottom padding.

I've tried removing either `#left` or `#right` from the page entirely to see if the CSS rules would be affect, but it didn't do anything.

What can I do about this? Is this some kind of bug? Is there something wrong with my code that I'm not seeing for whatever reason?

I hope I made sense. Thanks ahead of time!

Comment: The `a, b` (grouping) has lower precedence than `a b` (descendant) so the ID selectors are only applied to the `h1`s.

Comment: #left h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6 is only effecting h1 and not h2 through h6.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Write like this:

```
#left h1, #left h2, #left h3, #left h4, #left h5, #left h6 {
    padding: 10px;
    color: black;
}
#right h1, #right h2, #right h3, #right h4, #right h5, #right h6 {
    padding: 0px 10px;
}
```

Comment: Thank you! After years of writing CSS, I still didn't know that. Of course, I was also writing at five in the morning. Anyway, thanks a bunch!

Answer (score 2):

"Unrelated"? Because you prefixed the *line* with `#left`?
No. You have to prefix every sub-selector with `#left` to get the desired result.

```
#left h1, h2, h3, ... {}
/* is equivalent to */
#left h1 {}
h2 {}
h3 {}
```

Should be:

```
#left h1, #left h2, #left h3, ... {}
```

I agree, duplicating that much is not fun. To increase your productivity, you can use a CSS-preprocessor, such as [LESS](http://lesscss.org/) or [SASS](http://sass-lang.com/), then next the selectors:

```
/* Note: THIS IS NOT PURE CSS, USE A CSS PRE-PROCESSOR */
#left {
    h1, h2, h3, h4 { ... }
}
```